# Can I use a DVI splitter to be connected to a monitor and TV but only to use either one at a time?

Tags: windows-vista

Can I use a splitter to be connected to my monitor and TV when I will only be using one attachment at a time? Solely when surfing the Internet, etc. using the PC monitor and watching videos from YouTube, etc. using the TV.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think a DVI switch box is what you should buy:

http://www.google.com/search?q=DVI+switch+box

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the capabilities of the splitter. If the splitter was with no interface, then it would probably duplicate the monitor, however if it is more advanced or has a physical switch, then you can probably switch either between the monitor and TV, or have both displays showing in your display settings.

Comment: hi, thank you for replying. i'm not that knowledgeable about computers,just a basic user. any recommendation where i can buy one or perhaps a brand which won't have any "interface?"